# How to pass the list of items from stored procedure through ajax or html data

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

From my Controller i do have the process of list output through the stored procedure that came from Entity Framework (edmx) :

**Controller Side:**

```
    [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult DeleteApprovalTransferNo(string selectedOption)
    {

        if (selectedOption.Equals("transferList")){
            try
            {
                var output = deleteApprovalSrv.GetPendingTrfApprovalList(Convert.ToDecimal(SessionUserInfo.CurrentBranchCode));
                return Json(output, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString());
            }


        }



    }
```

**HTML :**

```
 <input type="radio"  name ="selectList" value="transferList" /> Transfer No &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input  type="radio" name ="selectList" value="rcrList" /> Rcr No &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-xs g-mt-minus-2" id="LoadBtn"><i class="material-icons">launch</i></button>
```

**Scripting :**

```
<script>
$("#LoadBtn").click(function () {

    var selectedOption = $("input:radio[name=selectList]:checked").val()

    if(selectedOption == "transferList") {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/@Controller/DeleteApprovalTransferNo',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: JSON.stringify({ selectedOption: selectedOption }),
            success: function (response) {

                if (response != null) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            },
            error: function (response) {

                alert(response);
            }    
        });


    }
    else {

        alert(selectedOption);
    }

});
```

How to pass the list of items from controller local variable named "Output" to HTML process using ajax function. So that i can deliberate those data in each table in the view model.

The stored procedure result with different parameter string,int, decimal.
How can i store it from the list output of the service process to ajax function then deliberate each data from different HTML attributes such as table data

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking - you are already passing `output` to the client using your `return Json(..)` code (as a side note, its a POST so you do not need `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`)

Comment: Through my response from alert window `[object Object]` .

Comment: We do not know what `output` is! - it looks like its a collection so you would need to iterate through `response`